# Preterit regular form pronounced like in the word "dead"

Tags: verbs, pronunciation

Sometimes I hear the termination of the preterit of regular verbs pronounced like in the word "dead".

Example : loaded pronounced "low dead"

Is that a legitimate pronunciation? Which region pronounces like this (other than the French)?

Comment: As broad guidance: British English. loaded **1** /ˈləʊdɪd/(RP or higher register), **2**ˈləʊdəd/(Common), **3**/ˈləʊdɛd/(Midlands)   (Other regions tend towards /ləʊdəd/ but the /əʊ/ vowel and the /dɪd/ may change,)

Comment: Welsh people may well say 'low-dead' for 'loaded'.